# Trying to display simple View listing all the rows MVC 6

Tags: controller, view, asp.net-core-mvc

I get this strange error:
MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.

I've made my objects as simple as possible just trying to get a handle on something that works with this Roles management.

The MVC 6 application works for Register and Login for single users. I can even make Roles and assign them on startup. But any attempt to do anything else has me thwarted. I am just trying to display a list of roles.

Controller:

```
namespace MVC6.Controllers
{

    //[Authorize(Roles = Utilities.Security.AdminRole)]
    public class RolesManagementController : Controller
    {

        // GET: /RolesManagement/

        public ActionResult Index(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

          return View(RoleManager.Roles.ToList());

        }
```

Simple Index View:

```
@model List<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Roles";
}


<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<br /><br />

<fieldset>
    <table id="roles" class="display">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="20%">Role Name</th>
                <th width="20%">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (null != Model)
            {
                foreach (var role in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @role.Name
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

I start the app in debug with a break point inside of the ActionResult, just to see, and it never hits the breakpoint and returns this error:

MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.

I get nothing, blank, nada, when I type "http://localhost:61849/RolesManagement"in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to inject a dependency directly into an action method you need to use the `[FromServices]` attribute. Check the [asp docs](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/controllers/dependency-injection.html#action-injection-with-fromservices):

> Sometimes you don’t need a service for more than one action within
>   your controller. In this case, it may make sense to inject the service
>   as a parameter to the action method. This is done by marking the
>   parameter with the attribute `[FromServices]`

So your code would look like:

```
public ActionResult Index([FromServices]IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
  return View(RoleManager.Roles.ToList());
}
```

You might also want to change your controller so those dependencies are provided in the constructor (In which case you don't need the attribute). That would be cleaner IMHO.

Comment: "those dependencies are provided in the constructor" . . . not sure where that is. Kinda new at this. Your [FromServices] is a a great idea. I ended up finding out that I had to overide the configuration settings in Startup.cs to get the connection string to work. I accept your answer.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the [docs](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/controllers/dependency-injection.html#dependency-injection-and-controllers), where there is a nice and simple introduction to constructor injection using ASP 5 and MVC 6 controllers.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I see more every day.